# Normalize then validate unique entry in a custom module field

Tags: modules, custom-field, validation

I have a custom text field in a module that the user populate with an EAN number. The input is getting validate by a "match" validator and then is serialized before save to get ride of the various variants of the EAN the user can enter ("978-2-87929-647-0", "978.2.87929.647.0" and so on…).
But now I need to validate is uniqueness and I can't find the right way to do this.

How can I normalize the input and then test if this normalized value already exists in the DB?

I cannot find a way to get the actual user input and normalize it before validate it.

I guess I have to use the "UniqueValidator" to test if the entry already exists in the DB.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If your model somehow extends Yii's [Model](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model) (which I think it does because you use Yii validators), you can use the [`beforeValidate()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#beforeValidate()-detail) method to change attribute values before validation:

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    // Before validation, normalize the attribute's value with whatever method you create for it
    $this->attribute = $this->yourNormalizationMethod($this->attribute);
}
```

After that, you can use Yii's [UniqueValidator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator) to make sure the attribute's value is unique. The docs show you some of it's possible configs, I'm sure you can make it work!

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.
Unfortunately, the "beforeValidate()" method does not seems to fire up.
public function beforeValidate() {
 return false;
}
does not raise anything in the Craft CP.
Where should I declare this function?
Do you have any example of this method working in a Field class?